# GParted shows Raid1 partition as Ext4, how can I correct that?

Tags: lvm, mdadm, raid1, gpt, gparted

As I've recently bought some extra disks to store my VM disks redundantly, hoping for some increased read performance and redundancy in case drives fail, I started building a RAID array.

I've currently created an `RAID1` array with 2 disks (I intend to add a 3rd disk to the array). On top of the RAID, I've created a `LVM PV`. Now, when I want to manage my drives with `gparted`, it tells me that one of the RAID-used partitions is `Ext4` instead of `linux-raid`.

[image]

The part that confuses me is that I have a `RAID0` array with 2 other disks which shows `linux-raid` as type for the RAID-used partitions. And I have a `RAID10` array with only 2 partitions (I know it's basically `RAID1` but I realized only afterwards I won't have enough disks to have benefits from it, so I'm actually migrating away) which also properly shows linux-raid as the type for the 2 RAID-used partitions.

[image: GParted does show correctly on another disk]

My question basically is, how can I fix this. While in the end it's not a big threat as I will rarely be using gparted, an annoying thing is that it has a warning about the ext4 system since it's considered broken.

Some extra information. `/dev/sdc` was previously used as whole-disk LVM. All partitions were made using `parted` on the server using `mkpart` and default type (which was `ext2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in a position to re-create the RAID and restore any data you require, then you might try using the **Partition -> Format to -> Cleared** menu option in GParted to wipe out all metadata signatures within the partition.

WARNING:  Be sure to have a backup of all your data first, as this will effectively remove access to the data on the partition / drive.

Comment: Ha, I didn't think of that, I can certainly rebuild the RAID array as I have 2 copies on other drives. I'll try that.